# How do you breed a polar bear?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you breed a polar bear in Minecraft?
I went to the [breeding section of the Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Breeding), but polar bears were not included.

Comment: If you go to the [Baby Animals Section](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Breeding#Baby_animals) it shows the polar bear cub.  I'm assuming you need to two polars bears near one another (just like you would cows), but instead of wheat, try raw fish (it be weird if polar bears at wheat)?  If not, then maybe you can't invoke breeding with them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turns out, you **cannot** breed a polar bear.

[Reddit Thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/4n1r33/how_do_you_breed_polar_bears/)

[Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Polar_Bear/)